# Laravel/Lumen: How to authorize Controller access?

Tags: php, laravel, authorization, lumen

This is my first Laravel/Lumen project therefore my knowledge is not the best yet.

My Route:

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'rest/v1','middleware' => 'auth'], function($router) {
    $router->get('articles','ArticleController@index');

    $router->get('article/{id}','ArticleController@getarticle');
});
```

My Controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller{
    public function index(){
        if(!CapabilityService::currentUserCan('fetch_basic_content')) {
            return response('Insufficient permissions.', 401);
        }
        return response()->json(Article::all());
    }

    public function getArticle($id){
        if(!CapabilityService::currentUserCan('fetch_basic_content')) {
            return response('Insufficient permissions.', 401);
        }
        return response()->json(Article::find($id));
    }
}
```

This is very cumbersome of course, especially as it is the same permission for accesssing all functions within my Controller. However I have to use my custom `CapabilityService` in order to check the permissions. How can I implement this better?

Comment: What about creating a [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authorization#creating-policies)

Comment: Do policies work for Controllers, too?

Comment: yes you can use controller helpers like this `$this->authorize('update', $post);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by creating a new middleware.

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'rest/v1','middleware' => ['auth','your-custom-middleware']], function($router) {
    $router->get('articles','ArticleController@index');

    $router->get('article/{id}','ArticleController@getarticle');
});
```

Now in your middleware `handle` method do something like

```
if(!CapabilityService::currentUserCan('fetch_basic_content')) {
            return response('Insufficient permissions.', 401);
        }
return $next($request);
```

Comment: One interesting way to solve it without policies or gates, thanks.